# Cannot start PowerShell - "Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: ... [process exited with code 2]"

Tags: windows, powershell, exception

[image: https://pastebin.com/x4Q22dPj]

**Error log**

```
    Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException: External component has thrown an exception.
       at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 collection)
       at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.UpdateFormats(ExecutionContext context, Boolean update)
       at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState.Bind_UpdateFormats(ExecutionContext context, Boolean updateOnly)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
[process exited with code 2]
```

I'm getting this error only for PowerShell on my pc. How to resolve this?

Comment: since i can't use your PICTURE of text to do searches ... i have no freaking idea what the error may be caused by. [*frown*] ///// lookee >>> Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? - Meta Stack Overflow — https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Hey Lee, thanks for the info. Let me edit my question :)

Comment: thank you! this >> `External component has thrown an exception.` << led me to >> Powershell Crashing after launch. · Issue #12425 · PowerShell/PowerShell — https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12425 <<, AND this >> windows 10 - Unhandled Powershell error on launch - Super User — https://superuser.com/questions/1211793/unhandled-powershell-error-on-launch << ///// they both seem to point to dotnet problems that were triggered by different KB/hotfix installs. you may need to uninstall the most recent MS bug installers [patches], OR use a restore point, OR reinstall windows [ugh!].